# Use other environment variables in PATH definition

Tags: environment-variables

I've been wondering if there is a way to set the PATH system variable using other system variables. For example my /etc/environment currently looks like

```
PATH="........other stuff........ :$SCALA_HOME/bin"
SCALA_HOME="/usr/lib/scala/scala-2.11.4"
```

But I can't get the path to actually use the SCALA_HOME variable I defined.  When I type 'scala' into the terminal it isn't recognized as a command.

I know I could just add the actual value of SCALA_HOME to the path like this...

```
PATH="........other stuff........ :/usr/lib/scala/scala-2.11.4/bin"
```

But I feel like this is repetitive and there should be a way to do it the way I was trying.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As muru said, this is a duplicate question. You can't do it in `/etc/environment`, but you can create e.g. `/etc/profile.d/mypath.sh` and give it this contents:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin"
```

Reference: [EnvironmentVariables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables)